# source[0] of type java.lang.Integer cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.CharSequence[]

Tags: android

I am trying to diplay AlertBuild dialog after getting the intent in the `onNewIntent` method from the `onPostexecute` method. `routeList` has [1,9,13]. Currently I am getting this error `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type java.lang.Integer cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.CharSequence[]`

```
ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras
                .getIntegerArrayList("stop_route"); //[1,9,13]
        int routeListSize = routeList.size();
        if(routeListSize > 0){

        CharSequence charSequence[] = routeList
                .toArray(new CharSequence[routeList.size()]);
        for (int i = 0, size = routeList.size(); i < size; i++) {
            charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select");

                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to change your `for` like so:

```
String[] charSequence = new String[routeList.size()];
        for (int i = 0, i<routeList.size(); i++) {
            charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
        }
```

instead of:

```
CharSequence charSequence[] = routeList
                .toArray(new CharSequence[routeList.size()]);
        for (int i = 0, size = routeList.size(); i < size; i++) {
            charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: It'd be nice to have an explanation on why this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in that `CharSequence` can take only string values, but your `routeList` type is `Integer`. So when you fill `charSequence[i]` with data, you need to change item types to `String`.

Wrong: `charSequence[i] = routeList.get(i);`

Right: `charSequence[i] = routeList.get(i).toString();`